# Unable to Sum Cost for Chart (Bar Graph) in APEX

Tags: sql, charts, oracle-apex, apex

I am trying to create a graph where the x-axis is the "REASON_FOR_SCRAP" column from my table, and the Y-axis is the sum of the values from the "CHARGED_COST" column. This is where my code is at this moment, hoping someone would be able to figure it out:

```
    select sum(SCRAP_BODY_SYSTEM.CHARGED_COST) as CHARGED_COST,
        SCRAP_BODY_SYSTEM.REASON_FOR_SCRAP as REASON_FOR_SCRAP 
    from SCRAP_BODY_SYSTEM SCRAP_BODY_SYSTEM
    group by SCRAP_BODY_SYSTEM.REASON_FOR_SCRAP
```

For some reason each data entry per a category shows up as another bar instead of summing into the same bar for each category like shown below:

[image]

What is weird is if I change it to a pie chart it sums up all the values normally.

Comment: Nothing obviously wrong (from what you said so far). I created sample bar graph on Scott's EMP table (summing salaries per department), looks OK. Consider creating an example on apex.oracle.com; let us know login credentials so that we could have a look.

Comment: I tried this with some dummy data and it worked as expected - 1 bar per reason for scrap. What does your query return - do you effectively have 1 row per "reason for scrap" ? There are a lot of settings to charts and we don't have your data. Chances of getting help will be a lot higher if you provide a detailed description of what you did exactly with some sample data. 
Or you could request a workspace on apex.oracle.com, setup a testcase there and ask to have a look at it.

Comment: I effectively have 1 row per "reason for scrap" I unfortunately would not be able to give login information as I am restricted to my company account. Any idea of what possible settings it could it be?